# Stacked bar and regular bar in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I have the following `df`:

```
    region    product    delivery    price
1   Japan     laptop     yes         500
2   Japan     printer    n/a         200 
3   America   laptop     no          600
4   America   printer    n/a         300
5   China     laptop     yes         400
```

If we exclude the `delivery` column, the below code generates a bar graph with `region` on the x-axis such that for each `region`, there are two side-by-side columns (one for `laptop` and one for `printer`) representing the respective aggregations of `price`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(region)) + geom_bar(aes(weight=price, fill=product), position="dodge")
```

I now want only the `laptop` column to be stacked by its aggregate partitions, namely, `delivery==yes` and `delivery==no`. The `printer` column should not be affected at all. Essentially, for each `Region`, the `laptop` column will have a stack consisting of two groups, and the `printer` column will have only one group as usual. Imagine this to be the case where a company sells printers and laptops, but only laptops have a delivery option.

Thanks! All of my attempts so far either stack the two `laptop` groups on top of the `printer` group or produce 3 separate columns, 2 for each group pertaining to `laptop` and one for `printer`.

Comment: Is this `ggplot(df, aes(region)) + geom_bar(aes(weight=price, fill=delivery),position="dodge")+facet_wrap(.~product)` what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively you are trying to have both "position_dodge" and "position_stack" on the `geom_bar`, which you can't do directly. However, you can do it indirectly through faceting. Making a few stylistic tweaks gives the kind of effect I think you are looking for.

```r
ggplot(within(df, delivery[delivery == "n/a"] <- NA), aes(product)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = price, fill = delivery), 
           position = "stack", colour = "gray50") +
  facet_grid(.~region, switch = "x") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.5, 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("no", "yes"),
                    values = c("gold", "deepskyblue"), na.value = "tomato") +
  labs(x = "Products by Region") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray90"),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "points"))
```

[image]

Note though that I had to modify your example data because you didn't actually have any laptops that were both "yes" and "no" in the same region. Therefore the data used was:

```
df <- structure(list(region = c("Japan", "Japan", "Japan", "America", 
      "America", "America", "China"), product = c("laptop", "laptop", 
      "printer", "laptop", "laptop", "printer", "laptop"), delivery = c("yes", 
      "no", "n/a", "no", "yes", "n/a", "yes"), price = c(500L, 400L, 
      200L, 600L, 620L, 300L, 400L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
      "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))

df
#>    region product delivery price
#> 1   Japan  laptop      yes   500
#> 2   Japan  laptop       no   400
#> 3   Japan printer      n/a   200
#> 4 America  laptop       no   600
#> 5 America  laptop      yes   620
#> 6 America printer      n/a   300
#> 7   China  laptop      yes   400
```

Comment: @HarryStuart you could change the `n/a` values in your data frame to `NA`

Comment: Okay great, I'm out at the moment, but I'll test your solution soon. Thanks!

Comment: thanks that works perfectly! If it's note too much to ask, I'd really like to see the sum of `price` for each partition of a bar and then a sum of `price` for the total bar above the bar. geom_text just shows each individual price which isn't particularly useful